# Access private DockerHub repo in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry, docker-machine

I am trying to deploy a docker swarm using Digital Ocean's docker-machine driver.

This is currently a single node that contains several public DockerHub images, and one private.

I am having difficulties in configuring it to accept the private image properly.

I have SSHed into the node, and used `docker login`. After that, I was able to properly `docker pull` the private image.

But, when trying to run `docker stack deploy -c myapp.yml myapp`, I am getting this warning:

```
image me/myapp:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access me/myapp:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different versions of the image.
```

What do I need to do to properly login to a private registry in docker swarm mode?

Answer (score 3):

You need the `--with-registry-auth` flag, e.g.:

```
docker stack deploy -c myapp.yml --with-registry-auth myapp
```

From the `docker stack deploy --help` output:

```
--with-registry-auth     Send registry authentication details to Swarm agents
```

Comment: In case somebody wondered, the last arg is the swarm name (and not some authentication token or something); so more generically written the deployment takes form `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth my_swarm_name`

Comment: @PMarecki it's the stack name, same as you'd include in a deploy command without the flag. The `--with-registry-auth` flag takes no options, it passes you local credentials from previous login commands to the nodes running the containers.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to do docker login to repo then you do stack deploy with --with-registry-auth flag.